A pandigital alphametic
Find, as Ed Pegg did, at least one solution of this pandigital alphametic:
                     A x BC x DEF = GHIJ.

How many solutions does it have altogether?
(GHIJ is thus a Melissa number, one which can be expressed as the product of numbers none of which uses any of the digits in the original number.)

Not so important, but Is B,D or G equal zero alowed?

If we don't allow B, D, or G to equal zero, there are:

 Only two solutions:

 1 x 26 x 345 = 8970
 2 x 14 x 307 = 8596


If we allow B, D, or G to equal zero, there are:

 70 more solutions with either B or D equal to zero. There are no solutions with G equal to zero.

I verified these answers with a SAT solver.
